# error C3646 : unknown override specifier

Tags: c++, compiler-errors

I'm trying to create a class `network` that you can create a network with parameters like the network ip.. and I want to pass also some nodes  like the number of notebook, so on the network constructor I can create an array of notebook type, but it show me the following error , I don't know why,
please be patient I'm a beginner :C

I'll paste the essential code so if you need more for understand the issue I'll write to you, thanks.

**class Network:**

```
#pragma once
#include <iostream>
#include "Node.h"
#include "IpAdress.h"
using namespace std;

class Network{
    protected:
        NoteBook _notebook[100];
}
```

**class Notebook:**

```
#pragma once
#include <iostream>
#include "Node.h"
#include "IpAdress.h"
using namespace std;

class NoteBook : public Node {

    public:
         NoteBook() : Node() {
            _networkAdress = IpAdress();
            _hostAdress = IpAdress();
            _powerState = false;
         }
}
```

error C3646 :'_notebook': unknown override specifier

it also show me strange errors to to the line:" NoteBook _notebook[100];":

- syntax error: ','missing before '['
- syntax error: ','missing before '['
- syntax error: ')' missing before ';'
- unexpected token before ';'

Comment: Did you miss an include of NoteBook?

Comment: the class NoteNook is inside the file "Node.h" , so i included that, is a problem?

Comment: That seems to differ from your code sample. What I mean is if class NoteBook is in Node.h why would it include Node.h?

Comment: Are you declaring NoteBook in your header and also your cpp file? That could explain the code you presented. Remember you need to declare it only in the header not the source file.

Comment: ok now i included only one header to the respective cpp, like only  "Node.h" in Node.cpp and "Network.h" in "Network.cpp" but it still give me the error , for the second comment ,  what should i include (on Network.h) instead of "Node.h" if 
 the class NoteBook is inside that file?

Comment: oh i also did a mistake on the code that i posted, on the second code block is not "Node.h" but is "network.h" , yeah, sorry